# Django update the entry

Tags: django, django-models

How come it is not possible to save the entry when I fetch it by using `filter`?
It works if I fetch it with `get`.

I need to use `filter` since I'm using the serializer to return a JSON object. And Django's serializer doesn't like if it is not a QuerySet.

```
message = UserMessage.objects.filter(id=request.GET['msg_id'])
message[0].read = True
message[0].save()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless the `message` is evaluated and thus cached, the `message[0]` always hits DB, for example

```
>>> qs = User.objects.all()
>>> qs[0] is qs[0]
False
>>> bool(qs) # evaluate, len(qs) or iterating on qs also do
>>> qs[0] is qs[0]
True
```

you could assign it to variable

```
message = UserMessage.objects.filter(id=request.GET['msg_id'])[0]
message.read = True
message.save()
```

or use `update` directly, as jpic suggested:

```
UserMessage.objects.filter(id=request.GET['msg_id']).update(read=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [queryset update method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#update):

```
UserMessage.objects.filter(id=request.GET['msg_id']).update(read=True)
```